# When is an assignment necessary?

Tags: python, dictionary, methods, import, python-import

Consider the following two sepearte scripts `main.py`

```
# main.py
import foo

D = {}
foo.add_key(D)
print(D)
```

and `foo.py`

```
# foo.py
def add_key(D: dict):
    D['key'] = 'value'
    return D
```

Executing `main.py` yields `{'keys' : 'value'}`. I was wondering why this works, because I was thinking that I need to assign something along the line `D = foo.add_key(D)`. Now I'm thinking that I define something in `foo.py` which gets somehow send into `main.py` as well.

Comment: You pass a dictionary into your function, and your function modifies that dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

What you are using is known as an "output argument" or "output parameter".
You alter the original object that you send to the `foo.add_key` method.

Add some `print(id(D))` statements, to see that the object is indeed the same everywhere. Assignment in this case would be a self assignment as `a = a`.

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/322490/what-is-an-output-argument-as-refered-to-in-martins-clean-code) is a good discussion / explanation why there is a controversy on this technique and why it is not considered "Clean Code".

Comment: That terminology doesn't really apply to Python. There's nothing special about the *parameter*; it's the argument that invokes (via the assignment syntax) the mutating method `dict.__setitem__`.

Comment: The concept/terminology applies to all languages with objects. The `add_key`  method uses the input argument (implicitly) also as an output. The thing here is, that the object gets passed around and altered. If you are not aware of this, this can cause bugs and headaches. Some people use this concept as a crude way of message flow within their programs and than thinks become very hard to understand. Hence, the link to the discussion, which is - in my opinion - a good summary on what is happening and what are the issues here.

Comment: The linked answer is also very Java-centric. 1) `add_key` will work with *any* type that implemented the mapping protocol, not just `dict`s. My understanding is that Java support for generic functions was only added recently. 2) Every Python method that mutates its argument is fundamentally defined like this. `self` is the "output" parameter; it's just the calling syntax that hides the explicitly passing of the object to the method as an argument.

Comment: There's also the issue of Java not allowing top-level functions, and only supporting methods. If you are going to have to define a new class anyway, might as well make a subclass for whatever object you want to modify. Python doesn't have the limitation.